# Verilog: Instantiating arrays in modules

Tags: verilog, vivado

Let's say I have an adder module

```
module adder(
    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    output [4:0] F
    );
    
    assign F = A + B;
endmodule;
```

and a toplevel module:

```
module toplevel(
    input [3:0] X,
    input [3:0] Y,
    output [4:0] Z
);

adder adder_1(
   .A(X),
   .B(Y),
   .F(Z)
);
endmodule;
```

Where I want to instantiate the adder. Would I be able to instantiate a module by assigning numbers to individual bits in its array?

For example can I write something like,

```
adder adder_1(
   .A[0](X[0]),
   .A[1](X[1},
```

and so on. Is there a way I can directly assign bit 0 of A from the adder module to a bit in the top level module?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary wire if your intention is to do some logic operations
on the toplevel port `x` bit by bit, the example below ands the 2nd bit only
of the port `x` with `0` and then connects it to the adder module

a quick example

```
wire [3 : 0] temp;

assign temp[0] = x[0];
assign temp[1] = x[1] & 1`b0;
assign temp[2] = x[2];
assign temp[3] = x[3];


adder adder_1(
   .A(temp),
   .B(Y),
   .F(Z)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. in your case it would be like :

```
module toplevel(
    input [3:0] X,
    input [3:0] Y,
    output [4:0] Z
);

adder adder_1(
   .A({X[3],X[2],X[1],X[0]}),
   .B(Y),
   .F(Z)
);
endmodule;
```